WiFi connection issue in Ubuntu 24
I quickly downloaded and started installing Ubuntu 24 on the day of its release. However, I encountered errors during the installation process, causing it to stop and restart multiple times. I realized that the problem was with my internet connection. I selected the "Install without internet" option from the available choices, and the Ubuntu 24 operating system was installed.
The issue was that after connecting to WiFi, the connection would work for a few minutes and then drop. The system indicated that I was connected to WiFi in the settings, but the web browser and all other applications could not access the internet. It was as if I was not connected to the internet at all.
Disconnecting and reconnecting to WiFi would temporarily resolve the issue, but it would reoccur after a few minutes. I also tried connecting via LAN cable, and the connection was stable without any issues.
I don't think the problem is with the drivers, but if it is, I would appreciate some guidance on installing the WiFi drivers. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Ubuntu 24 multiple times, but the problem persists. I have no issues with Ubuntu 23, which works correctly.
$ lspci -knn | grep -i wireless
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2126]

Update:
$ service --status-all
 [ + ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  gdm3
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  openvpn
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ + ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  saned
 [ - ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ - ]  sssd
 [ + ]  sysstat
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common

$ service NetworkManager status
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-05-12 16:54:26 EDT; 10min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1107 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 9300)
     Memory: 18.1M (peak: 33.8M)
        CPU: 764ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1107 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

May 12 17:04:47 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547887.0463] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 12 17:04:47 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547887.0463] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed no lease
May 12 17:04:47 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547887.0463] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 12 17:04:47 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547887.0464] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
May 12 17:04:47 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547887.0723] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.112, acd pending
May 12 17:04:47 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547887.0725] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.112
May 12 17:05:02 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547902.2046] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 12 17:05:02 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547902.2046] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 12 17:05:02 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547902.2981] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 12 17:05:02 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547902.2982] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning

sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
[sudo] password for navid: 
May 12 16:54:25 local systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager.service - Network Man>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7493] NetworkMa>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7499] Read conf>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7585] manager[0>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7586] monitorin>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7610] hostname:>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7611] hostname:>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7618] dns-mgr: >
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7631] rfkill1: >
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7633] manager[0>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7633] manager[0>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7659] Loaded de>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7672] Loaded de>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7731] Loaded de>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7740] Loaded de>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7763] Loaded de>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7766] manager: >
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7766] manager: >
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7767] manager: >
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7788] settings:>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7788] settings:>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7788] ifupdown:>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7790] ifupdown:>
lines 1-23...skipping...
May 12 16:54:25 local systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager.service - Network Manager...
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7493] NetworkManager (version 1.46.0) is starting... (boot:ce8226d5-c8c0-4c95-9858-949fe7f221ce)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7499] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-a>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7585] manager[0x5fc6c73d76d0]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7586] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7610] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7611] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "local"
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7618] dns-mgr: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7631] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (d>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7633] manager[0x5fc6c73d76d0]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7633] manager[0x5fc6c73d76d0]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7659] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7672] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7731] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7740] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7763] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7766] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7766] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7767] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7788] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-settings-plugin-ifu>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7788] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7788] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7790] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
May 12 16:54:26 local generate[1231]: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4579] dhcp: init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4582] manager: (lo): new Loopback device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4595] device (lo): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4600] device (lo): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4608] device (lo): Activation: starting connection 'lo' (f71d45a9-926b-47e4-8c90-d3da0cb7a5c8)
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4618] manager: (enp5s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4622] device (enp5s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6526] device (wlp4s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6530] manager: (wlp4s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6532] device (wlp4s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6694] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
May 12 16:54:26 local systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6700] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6711] device (lo): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6714] device (lo): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6716] device (lo): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6726] device (lo): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6734] modem-manager: ModemManager available
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6751] device (lo): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6752] device (lo): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
lines 1-44
May 12 16:54:25 local systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager.service - Network Manager...
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7493] NetworkManager (version 1.46.0) is starting... (boot:ce8226d5-c8c0-4c95-9858-949fe7f221ce)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7499] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no->
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7585] manager[0x5fc6c73d76d0]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7586] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7610] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7611] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "local"
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7618] dns-mgr: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7631] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:04:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7633] manager[0x5fc6c73d76d0]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7633] manager[0x5fc6c73d76d0]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7659] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7672] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7731] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-bluetoo>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7740] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7763] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7766] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7766] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7767] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7788] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-settings-plugi>
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7788] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7788] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
May 12 16:54:25 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547265.7790] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
May 12 16:54:26 local generate[1231]: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4579] dhcp: init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4582] manager: (lo): new Loopback device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4595] device (lo): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4600] device (lo): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4608] device (lo): Activation: starting connection 'lo' (f71d45a9-926b-47e4-8c90-d3da0cb7a5c8)
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4618] manager: (enp5s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.4622] device (enp5s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6526] device (wlp4s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6530] manager: (wlp4s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6532] device (wlp4s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6694] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
May 12 16:54:26 local systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6700] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6711] device (lo): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6714] device (lo): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6716] device (lo): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6726] device (lo): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 12 16:54:26 local NetworkManager[1107]: <info>  [1715547266.6734] modem-manager: ModemManager available


Check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

I just updated this post can you help with this?
